# .xlsx or .csv file that holds the information about supply of bitcoin in time series

Tags: money-supply

I am developing a new alpha for algorithmic trading of bitcoin.

My basic Idea is to construct a function which maps a change of supply into the total buy/sell action.

and also I'd like to track the change of total liquidity of bitcoin.

To make this alpha, I need handleable .xlsx or .csv file that holds the information about supply of bitcoin in time series.

Any help for me to find this data? where can I find it?

Comment: By "supply" do you mean the [total number of bitcoin in circulation at a given time](https://blockchain.info/charts/total-bitcoins)? They're being created at a fairly constant rate.

Comment: @Geremia yes total number of bitcoin in circulation.

Comment: @Geremia why is it so constant?

Comment: They're not constant. The creation rate is constant.

Comment: @Beverlie The creation rate is constant, as Pieter said, so the amount of bitcoins in circulation grown about linearly. You can find those and other data that may be useful for your case by API on blockchain.info, bitcoinity.org, coin.dance and many other.